# Authorization Error handling when Authorization service down in Spring boot security doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my spring boot web app, I hit a third party service for Authorization and my application is just a content provider. Parent application uses site minder for authentication. My application gets user Id in header and makes call to third party  api to set UserDetails with authorities.

My requirement is to handle scenario when third party service for authorization is down. Currently in this case I set UserDetails with no roles and since every endpoint is bound by authorization so I get 403 if third party service for authorization is down.

But I want to display different message if user lacks authorization and if authorization service is down.

If I handle authorization service down by throwing custom exception from **UserDetailsServiceImpl -> loadUserByUserName()** then **RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter** encounters this exception and request gets filtered out. Any idea how to get this done ?

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
public class WebSecurityCustomConfig extends WebSecurityConfigAdapter {
 private UserDetailsService userDetails;
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
   http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*).permitAll()
   .anyRequests()
   .hasAnyAuthority("MODULEX","MODULEY");

 http.addFilterBefore(requestHeaderAuthFilter(), 
   BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customEntryPoint());
 }

 protect void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) {
   PreAuthenticaticatedAuthenticationProvider auth = new 
             PreAuthenticaticatedAuthenticationProvider ();
  auth.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new 
      UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>(userDetails));
  }
 }
```

**Custom UserDetailsService**

```
  public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final AuthorizationService authService;
    @Inject
     public CustoUserDetailsService(AuthorizationService authService) {
       this.authService = authService;
       }
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
         return new User(username, "", 
                 authService.getAuthorities(username));  
        // authService is a  third party jar and if their upstream service 
           //is down , it throws a runtime exception
      }
      }
```

If I handle their error as follows then I end up with 403 but I want 503 in case service is down and 403 if user doesnt have right authority for endpoint he is accessing.

**current handling auth service exception**

```
     public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
         try{
         return new User(username, "", 
                 authService.getAuthorities(username));  
       }
          catch(AuthServiceException e) {
               return new User(username, "", 
                 Collections.emptyList());  
               } 
      }
```

Comment: If I throw exception from userdetailsservice instead of handling then it doesn't hit CustomauthenticationEntryPoint which can be used to st appropriate response in case service is down

Comment: with above implementation user with no authority and if authorization see same error which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and override `commence()` method as follows.

```
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");

    }

}
```

And after that create a method in your `WebSecurityCustomConfig` class that initialize the `RestAuthenticationEntryPoint` class as follows.

```
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint ep = new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    return ep;
}
```

Then change your following line to `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customEntryPoint());`

to
`http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());`